# Get data based on exclude logic

Tags: mysql

Added Table for more context, i need data based below two conditions

1. Max (activity_date) with Open_amt <> 0 and
2. Exclude rows if Max (activity_date) with Open_amt = '0' and State = 'closed'

| Inv # | Account # | Activity | State | Open_Amt | Last Activity Dt | Seq | St_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Customer1 | Act-1 | Issued | 12.50 | 2022-02-18 | 455 | 2022-01-04 |
| 123 | Customer1 | Act-2 | Closed | 0.00 | 2022-03-05 | 567 | 2022-01-04 |
| 345 | Customer2 | Act-1 | Issued | 15.00 | 2022-02-18 | 467 | 2022-01-12 |
| 345 | Customer2 | Act-2 | Issued | 09.35 | 2022-02-25 | 488 | 2022-01-12 |
| 678 | Customer3 | Act-1 | Issued | 30.50 | 2022-03-20 | 589 | 2022-01-23 |
| 678 | Customer3 | Act-2 | Closed | 00.00 | 2022-03-30 | 623 | 2022-01-23 |
| 678 | Customer3 | Act-3 | Issued | 30.50 | 2022-04-02 | 788 | 2022-01-23 |
| 678 | Customer3 | Act-4 | Issued | 05.50 | 2022-04-10 | 988 | 2022-01-23 |

for above table below is the output

| Inv # | Account # | Activity | State | Open_Amt | Last Activity Dt | Seq | St_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | Customer2 | Act-2 | Issued | 09.35 | 2022-02-25 | 488 | 2022-01-12 |
| 678 | Customer3 | Act-4 | Issued | 05.50 | 2022-04-10 | 988 | 2022-01-23 |

Comment: i do curious what have you tried? also, `Open_amt <> 0` logically will exclude `Open_amt = '0'`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are really running `mysql` given the column names. But here it goes the query in `mysql`:

```
with
 latest as (select Inv, Max(Last_Activity_Dt) as date
    from tbl group by (Inv))

select t.*
from latest as lt
 left join tbl as t
 on lt.Inv = t.Inv
 and lt.date = t.Last_Activity_Dt
where t.state <> 'Closed' and Open_Amt <> 0;
```

It uses CTE which available on mysql 8. The CTE is used to get all of the `latest` record for a given customer based on their `Inv`.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fAJen86r2qReZYHdhxtcj/0

Comment: it gives null result though i applied exact logic in actual dataset...when i remove logic 'and lt.date = t.Last_Activity_Dt', it shows multiple lines which are not 'Closed'.

Comment: @rkpg thats odd for sure. if you remove the `Last_Activity_Dt` there is no guarantee that its the latest record given you have multiple entries of the same `Inv`. this is why, having a `primary key` is important..

Comment: @rkpg you can check that the fiddle works. but again, i do wonder if its really a `mysql `or did you run the query on some arcane SAP stuff that claimed to be compatible with `sql`? there are many flavours of `sql` fyi. dont just assume every `sql` is `mysql`. and i hate dishonest question that misled people.